# xcode 7.1 fails when calling chown

Tags: ios, macos, xcode7

I am building an iOS project on yosemite with xcode 7.1 on a macbook pro where i login with network (Domain) credentials.
If i do `ls -l` I can see my files belonging to myuser:24252342423
When Xcode tries to perform the chown command while building the archive it tries to do:  `chown -RH myuser:MYDOMAIN\\Domain\ Users <filepath>` 
and that generates an error: `chown: MYDOMAIN\Domain\ Users: illegal group name`
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to me being connected in vpn and thus the groupname was not resolved, once i got back to office the problem was automatically solved.